# Convert svg to png imagemagick black border around path

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I am on macOs Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109)

My imagemagick details (installed with brew)

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-35 Q16 x86_64 2019-03-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib
```

I have a basic svg (adopted from W3Schools example):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="52" height="52" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <path fill="#fff" d="M22 0 L33 52 L12 42 Z">
</path>
</svg>
```

That looks like this (Gapplin):

[image: Gapplin view]

Now when i convert it to png like so:

```
convert -background none -density 9600 -resize 32x "myFile.svg" "myFile.png"
```

i get a perfect image, except it has a black border:

[image: after conversion]

I tried just about every variation of command options for imagemagick that had to do with `color` or `black` and sadly it never comes out with what i want - transparent background, solid white path (as described by fill on the SVG).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In ImageMagick, SVG files can be rendered by any one of three tools: Imagemagick's MSVG/XML, RSVG delegate and Inkscape, usually in order of increasing accuracy.

I just tried the following command with Inkscape 0.92.4 and it comes out totally white. If Inkscape is installed Imagemagick will use it automatically. But in this case it is not working well with that file.

```
magick test.svg test2.png
```

But it works fine if I added -background none

```
magick -background none test.svg test2.png
```

I get a white triangle on a transparent background.

or if I want a black background

```
magick -background black test.svg test2.png
```

When I force Imagemagick to use MSVG, I get a white triangle with a simple black outline on a white background. So again not correct by your comments.

```
magick MSVG:test.svg test2.png
```

If I add -background none, then I get white triangle with black outline on a transparent background.

```
magick -background none MSVG:test.svg test2.png
```

But if I just want a black background, then

```
magick -background black MSVG:test.svg test2.png
```

I then get a white triangle on a black background. But I suspect the white triangle is slightly smaller from the black border it had.

When I force the use of RSVG 2.44.12 by creating an entry in the delegates.xml file, I get a white triangle on a transparent background, which I assume is what you want.

```
magick RSVG:test.svg test3.png
```

or

```
magick -background none RSVG:test.svg test3.png
```

You can tell if your Imagemagick has MSVG/XML or RSVG by

```
magick -list format
```

and look for the line starting with SVG. At the end of that line it will either say XML or RSVG. You cannot tell about Inkscape with this method.

Check to see what you are using for your SVG renderer and its version. Also the version of libpng. Mine is 1.6.36

From your version information, I do not see rsvp listed. So I assume you are using MSVG, but it could be Inkscape if you have installed that on your system.

I am on Mac OSX Sierra with Imagemagick 7.0.8.35 Q16.

Comment: So running `magick -list format | grep SVG` i get ```     MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
      SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)
     SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)```
I have not installed InkScape. I tried `brew install librsvg` but that did not add RSVG to the magick formats :(

Comment: You have to install librsvg with Imagemagick. So you may need to reinstall both. But I am not an expert with Homebrew. So consult with them or some one else. However if you install Inkscape, then Imagemagick will use it automatically. You will not have to install Imagemagick again as with a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem converting SVG to PNG with PHP - black lines around the path. I install Inkscape on the server that was processing the image and that seemed to fix it, no code change necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, switching converters did not help.
Thus I experimented with the SVG itself.

And adding `stroke-opacity="0"` to the svg (or the individual paths if you dont want everything to have no outline) helped.

I assume that there is some default for stroke values that the converters set that makes them visible and this defines them as invisible on the svg level